# Java Swing SHIFT_DOWN_MASK and VK_NUMPAD on Windows platform

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am trying to listen to shift + numpad keys and I am facing issues on Windows platform.

Here is the code:

```
// Add keystrokes
// i = 96 --> KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0
// i = 105 --> KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9
for (int i = 96; i < 106; i++) {
    String text = String.valueOf(i);

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(i, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK), text);
    rootPane.getActionMap().put(text, speakerActionN);
}
```

This code work fine on Linux platform but it is probably overridden by built in Windows shortcuts, which has an effect of key handlers not being called.

Does anybody know of any solution which wouldn't omit the use of these shortcuts?

Comment: Interesting.  I wrote up a test program, and it appears Windows synthesizes a key release for Shift, when I press a keypad key while NumLock is on.  There is no standard way to distinguish such a “fake” key release, but you might be able to use timestamps to guess at it, since a manual release of Shift is unlikely to occur within a few milliseconds of a following key press.